# I faced exclamation mark error

Tags: android

I have an error in the project, but I cant find it.
I see only one  exclamation mark in my project.
I cant start my project because I got this error "Your project contanis erros(s), pleas fix before running you application".

[image]

Comment: Does it uses any library ??

Comment: Sometimes it seems that I have to expand all the folders until I see a file with a red line under it to find where the error is

Comment: yes I do, signalR, gson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm):

> Decorates Java projects and working sets that contain build path
>   errors

There can be several reasons. Most of the times it may be some of the below reasons ,

1. You have deleted some of the .jar files from your /lib folder
2. You have added new .jar files
3. you have added new .jar files which may be conflict with others

So what to do is we have to resolve those missing / updating / newly_added jar files.

- right click on the project and go to properties
- Select Java Build Path
- go to the Libraries tab
- Remove the references of the jar files which you have removed
  already. There will be a red mark near them so you can identify them
  easily.
- Add the references to the newly added .jar files by using Add JARs
  Refresh the project

This will solve the problem if it's because one of the above reasons.

Still Facing problem ??Try this:

Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Android -> Build and uncheck "Skip packaging and dexing until export or launch" then restart Eclipse.